# Basics of .net config files

Tags: c#, configuration-files

I am looking for an explanation and introduction to creating C#.Net configuration files. Ive looked on MSDN and did some searches, but cant find a document or web page that can give some sort of introduction to creating config files. Structure, syntax etc.

A generic example is the RegisterWellKnownServiceType() creation. In the a class structure you call it by its full name, RegisterWellKnownServiceType(...), but in the config file you only refer to it as

```
<service>
    <wellknown ..(Insert variables).. />
</service>
```

Why would you abbreviate RegisterWellKnownServiceType to wellknown only ? I would have expected you to use the full RegisterWellKnownServiceType to use it? Im am sure there are more examples like this, so a couple of links or a generic explanation on config files will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: That doesn't help me. So why not just use servicetype or any other set of arbitrary words to shorten it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.NET configuration files are XML files.

Read [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1fk1t1t0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) what configuration sections/settings are available, but I wouldn't put too much effort into it as these probably aren't written in stone. For ASP.NET configuration documentation look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dayb112d%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). These configuration settings are for configuring components of .NET framework that are used in your application. It seems architects of .NET components used whatever naming conventions they intuitively felt right for this or other element, and I don't see any specific rule between class names and config elements.

The wellknown element is defined under Remoting Settings Schema.

Note that in the code of your application you can read/write the .config files, so you can come up with your own configuration sections for your app, and use whatever naming conventions you like.

Comment: Thanks m0s. I had a look at those links but its still a bit unclear. Ill revisit it later with a clear mind. With respect to the choosing your own names, it set a bit more clarity on the issue of naming the various config calls. Thanks